# OpenCV + gym-retro: Invalid number of channels in input image

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, openai-gym

Been messing around with gym-retro and OpenCV. I have been looking at other code examples and tutorials. Several of them seem to be coded the same way but when I do it I get the following error. Has there been some type of update or something? Any suggestions on a fix welcome. I can comment out the reshaping and conversion to greyscale and it works. However then I am feeding too much info to my NN.

```
import retro
import numpy as np
import cv2
import neat
import pickle

env = retro.make('SuperMarioBros3-Nes', '1Player.World1.Level1')

def eval_genomes(genomes, config):
    for genome_id,genome in genomes:
        ob = env.reset()
        ac = env.action_space.sample()
        inx, iny, inc = env.observation_space.shape
        inx = int(inx/8)
        iny = int(iny/8)
        net = neat.nn.recurrent.RecurrentNetwork.create(genome, config)
        current_max_fitness = 0
        fitness_current = 0
        frame = 0
        counter = 0
        xpos = 0
        xpos_max = 0
        done = False
        

        while not done:
            env.render()
            frame += 1
            #print(ob)
            
            ob = cv2.resize(ob, (inx,iny))
            ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            ob = np.reshape(ob, (inx,iny))
            imgarray = np.ndarray.flatten(ob)
        
        nnOutput = net.activate(imgarray)
        
        ob, rew, done, info = env.step(nnOutput)
        #imgarray.clear()

config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,neat.DefaultSpeciesSet,neat.DefaultStagnation,'config-feedforward')

p = neat.Population(config)

winner = p.run(eval_genomes)
```

```
(gameai) C:\Users\dgilk\anaconda3\envs\gameai>python mario.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mario.py", line 45, in <module>
    winner = p.run(eval_genomes)
  File "C:\Users\dgilk\anaconda3\envs\gameai\lib\site-packages\neat\population.py", line 89, in run
    fitness_function(list(iteritems(self.population)), self.config)
  File "mario.py", line 32, in eval_genomes
    ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) c:\users\appveyor\appdata\local\temp\1\pip-req-build-k8sx3e60\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__cdecl cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xbf2c9cd3::Set<1,-1,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xbf2c9cd3::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 1
```

UPDATE:
Here is an output of the shrunken image. There appears to be color.
[snippet of observation window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59R8Z.png)

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems if you remove `ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)` sentence problem will be solved. The reason is the error says: `number of channels in input image is 1` means the image is a gray image.  So you may try to convert gray image to grayscale again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating a cv2 object with shape (inx,iny) here

```
   ob = cv2.resize(ob, (inx,iny)) # 1
   ob = cv2.cvtColor(ob, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # 2
```

cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY is expecting a color image which would have shape ( inx, iny, 3) , so check what shape you need your 'ob' to be , what  do you need  line 2 for ?

Comment: Thanks for your response! From my understanding we want to downsample the image and remove the colors so the neural net has less to process.

Comment: It had something to do with my numpy. It was greyscaling it twice for some reason. Thank you everyone!